# Can I create a Razor Form with HtmlAttributes only?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My problem is simple, im using a single view that works for create and update called UserView.cstml.

That view has a razor form section like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
...bla bla code
}
```

The problem is this, my pages are really very reusable, so **I CAN'T by any chanse**, send a value in the "Action" and "Controller" parameter, (they must remain as default). But I need to send the Html Attributes.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: (IDictionary<String, Object>)MyAttributes))
{
}
```

(The code above fails)

The reasson I need this, is to inform in HtmlAttributes that this form is 
enctype="multipart/form-data"

Maybe you know another way to make a multipart-form data form?

Thanks!

Comment: @FabioLuz ... take a moment to read the BOLD part, emphasizing that I CANT send the controller and the action... did you read the post?

Comment: thats why I sent you this as a comment instead of an answer... I was not sure about your question... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `null` for Action and Controller parameters, like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, MyAttributes))
{

}
```